# How to manage mix use of raw pointers and unique_ptr in different class ? (Exceptions ?)

Tags: c++, class, exception, unique-ptr

I have a container of objects stored with `unique_ptr`, for simplicity say i have only one object :

```
class Container { std::unique_ptr<A> ptrA; }
```

I also have class that uses the object. These class take a raw pointer to these objects when they are constructed:

```
class B { A* a;
B(*A param) : a(param) }
```

They are created with : `B b = B(Container.ptrA.get()  );`

The Container class is supposed to outlive the `class B`. However I'd like my whole program not to crash in the case there is an issue or a bug in my class Container and the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope and get deleted.

My question is about the design you would take to manage this 1% case so my program can try to reload the data and avoid crashing suddenly, would you use exceptions ? If so where would you do try/catch ?

Thanks !

Comment: It seems like you want `std::shared_ptr` instead, depending on the ownership semantics of the `A` object.

Comment: "The Container class is supposed to outlive the class B. However I'd like my whole program not to crash in the case there is an issue or a bug ..." Well, you can catch the `SEGFAULT` signal and try to recover from it, but really this just sounds like wanting a "safer" language. Joachim Pileborg is correct that a `std::shared_ptr` will more or less work in this case, but the idea that you can write code that "should" work but is robust against ownership/lifetime errors is...pretty much anathema to the goals of low-level languages like C++ with explicit lifetime management, I think.

Comment: Biased plug: the Rust language (it's pretty new) enforces correct lifetime management *at compile-time*. This is arguably Rust's core value-add compared to other low-level languages, but it also drives some users away because it can make it harder to get your code to compile in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `std::unique_ptr` you're making a design decision: `Container` owns the pointer. Trying to work around that fact is only going to make your life harder.

But in fact you said `Container` outlives `B`. Why don't you just enforce that instead of being overly defensive against bugs that would probably break your program in several other ways?

Answer (score 4):

I would say don't use `shared_ptr` to hide bugs. If your `unique_ptr` is designed to outlive the *raw pointer* then I would want the program to crash if there is a bug. Then I have something to fix. It's much worse when the bugs go undetected because they are hidden from you. Remember, a crash gives you a *point of failure* to investigate. But if the bugs go undetected you may not be able to find what's making things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like your program not to crash, then use `std::shared_ptr` for both pointers.

That would be the easiest solution.

Otherwise, you will need to put in some kind of a mechanism by which the `Container` class tracks the number of instances of the `B` class, that use the same pointer, then throw an exception in the destructor if the `Container` is getting destroyed while there are still an instance of `B` somewhere. If its `unique_ptr` is getting blown away for some other reason, other than the destructor getting invoked, the same check would apply there, as well.

That's presuming that throwing an exception is what you would like to do to handle this edge case. It's not clear what you mean "can try to reload the data", but as then designer and the implementer of your application you need to decide how you are going to handle this situation. Nobody else can make the call for you, you know more about your overall application than anyone else. There is no universal, single answer here that will work best for every application in every situation.

But whatever you decide should be an appropriate course of action: throw an exception; or create a new instance of the object, stuff it into the `unique_ptr` and then update all native pointers in all the `B` classes that you're keeping track of, somehow; that would be your call to make. What's the best approach is a subjective call to make. There is no objective answer for that part.

Now, getting back to the technical aspects, keeping track of how many instances of the `B` class can be as simple as keeping a counter in the container, and have `B`'s constructor and destructor update it accordingly. Or maybe have `Container` keep a container of pointers to all instances of `B`. In either case, don't forget to do the right thing in the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

But I think it's just easier to use use a `std::shared_ptr` in both classes, and not worry about any of this. Even though doing this kind of class bookkeeping is not rocket science, why bother when you can simply have `std::shared_ptr` do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Philosophically: this is not a great idea, at least in C++.

> The Container class is supposed to outlive the class B. However I'd like my whole program not to crash in the case there is an issue or a bug ...

It sounds like you want a "safer" language.

The idea that you can write code that "should" work but is robust against ownership/lifetime errors is...pretty much anathema to the goals of low-level languages like C++ with explicit lifetime management, I think.

If you really want to write a program that simply *doesn't crash*, use a language with a runtime that manages memory and lifetimes for you—that is, a garbage-collected language like Java or Python. These languages are designed to "protect you from yourself," so to speak. In theory, they prevent you from encountering the sorts of errors you're describing by managing memory *for* you.

But part of the *point* of using low-level languages is to take advantage of explicit memory management. With C++ you can (in theory) write software that, in comparison to software written in managed languages, runs faster, has a smaller memory footprint, and releases system resources (such as filehandles) sooner.

### The *right* approach in C++ is the one you're already using.

Explicitly letting your container class *own* the underlying objects and representing this ownership using `unique_ptr` is *exactly correct* in modern C++, and there is no reason to expect this approach not to work if your system is carefully engineered.

The key question, though, is *how can you guarantee* that your `container` class will stay alive and keep your owned objects alive throughout the entire lifetime of the "user" objects (in this case `class B` instances)? Your question doesn't provide enough details about your architecture for us to answer this, because different designs will require different approaches. But if you can *explain* how your system (in theory) provides this guarantee, then you are probably on the right track.

### If you still have concerns, there *are* some approaches for dealing with them.

There are many reasons to have valid concerns about lifetime management in C++; a major one is if you are inheriting a legacy codebase and you're not sure it manages lifetimes appropriately.

This can happen *even with modern C++ features such as `unique_ptr`*. I'm working on a project that only got started last year, and we've been using C++14 features, including `<memory>`, since the beginning, and I *definitely* consider it a "legacy" project:

- Multiple engineers who were on the project have now left; 60,000+ lines are "unowned" in the sense that their original author is no longer on the project
- There are very few unit tests
- There are occasional segfaults :D

Note that a bug in your lifetime management may **not** cause a crash; if it did, that would be *fantastic*, because, as Galik says in their answer, this would give you a point of failure to investigate. Unfortunately, there's no way to *guarantee* that dereferencing a stale pointer will cause a crash, because this is (obviously) undefined behavior. Thus your program could keep running and silently do something utterly disastrous.

#### Signal-catching

However, a crash—specifically, a segfault—is the most *likely* result of the error you describe, because a segfault is something you can (sort of) program around.

This is the weakest approach in terms of what kinds of fault-handling behavior you can implement: simply catch the `SEGFAULT` signal and try to recover from it. Signal-catching functions have some pretty severe limitations, and in general if your lifetime management is screwed up there's probably no way to make reasonable guarantees about what memory you can trust and what memory you can't, so your program might be doomed no matter what you do when you catch the signal.

This is *not* a good approach to "fixing" broken software; however, it is a very reasonable way to provide a clean exit path for unrecoverable errors (e.g. it will allow you to emulate the classic "memory error at " error messages). Additionally, if all you want to do is to restart your entire application and hope for the best, you can probably implement this using a signal-catcher, although a better approach may be to implement a second "watcher" application that restarts your software when it crashes.

#### `std::shared_ptr`

Joachim Pileborg is correct that a `std::shared_ptr` will work in this case, but (1) `shared_ptr` has some overhead compared to raw pointers (if you care about that) and (2) it requires changing your entire lifetime-management scheme.

Also, as pointed out by Galik in the comments, when there is a lifetime-management bug, the lifetime of the owned object will be **extended**; the object will still exist after the `shared_ptr` has been removed from the container if any `shared_ptr`s in your `B` class instances are still active.

#### `std::weak_ptr`

Your best bet might be a [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). This *also* requires changing your lifetime-management scheme to use `shared_ptr`, but it has the benefit of not keeping old objects around just because a `shared_ptr` to them exists *somewhere* outside of your lifetime-managing containers.

### Not all low-level languages are this unforgiving, though.

I'm a bit biased because I *love* the philosophies behind the Rust language, so this is a bit of a plug. **Rust enforces correct lifetime-management *at compile-time.*** Rust is just as low-level as C++ in the sense that it gives full control over memory management, memory access, etc., but it's a "modern" high-level language in that it's closer to a redesigned version of C++ than it is to, say, C.

But the key point for our purposes is that the *limitations* Rust puts on you in terms of what it considers an "ownership" or lifetime-management error enable far better *guarantees* of program correctness than *any* possible static analysis of a C or C++ program ever could.

Comment: I don't really think "pick another language" answers the question to be honest. Just because some languages are more "forgiving" of programming design errors doesn't necessarily mean they actually protect you from those errors. There are things that `C++` programmers (like the OP) need to lean about lifetime management but "pick another language" doesn't teach them what those are.

Comment: @Galik That's...really not a good summary of my answer, which offers three (!) alternatives in C++. And I'm not sure what you mean about programming languages not "actually" protecting programmers from certain classes of errors.

Comment: @Galik I suppose I could edit my answer to clarify that the best approach in C++ is to understand memory-managing pointers and RAII, learn robust memory management techniques, and then *trust* them.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with your answer; I do not think we're fundamentally in disagreement.

Comment: By way of explanation remember that the `OP` said that if the raw pointer outlived the `std::unique_ptr` it would be a programming error. So this is about how to avoid that programming error. But replacing the `std::unique_ptr` and the *raw pointer* with `std::shared_ptr`s wouldn't actually solve such a programming error, it would simply hide it. Though it may alleviate the more obvious symptoms. The object would still be living longer than it was designed to live.

Comment: And not only is it living longer than it was designed to live it is keeping another object alive that was supposed to have died - the target of its `std::shared_ptr` - `A` in the `OPs` example. So not only is the incorrect behavior still present, it has possibly gotten worse.

Comment: With that in mind the way your answer reads to me is a bit like this: `C++` is too dangerous to use so 1) pick another language or 2) ignore the error or 3) hide the problem behind shared semantics or 4) same as 3).

Comment: The thing is that `C++` does what a lot of "managed" languages do not do. It allows fine control over ownership semantics. This is a very powerful tool but it comes with a relatively high learning curve. I tend to feel that carpet bombing code with *shared pointers* or moving to a language that shares pointers (even if you don't need shared semantics) simply avoids solving the actual problem - a design that clearly establishes objects' lifetimes.

Comment: I programmed in `Java` for quite a few years. But I believe that I can write safer, more correct code in `C++` because of "value semantics" and because of `RAII` but also because of the ability to not have to share every pointer. Knowing exactly when something is going to die can be a huge benefit. I also believe that `C++`'s tendency to "fail fast" in the face of an error can lead to more correct code. Languages that are are more "forgiving" of programming errors can hide them, and that can manifest as hard to spot, incorrect behavior.

Comment: BTW I did have a brief look at `Rust`. It does look interesting. I can't pretend to fully understand its treatment of *ownership* but it looks a bit like it has formalized *copy*, *move* and *shared* semantics into the language itself whereas `C++` has implemented them in terms of library facilities.

Comment: Again: I *completely agree* that using `shared_ptr` everywhere is unlikely to be an appropriate solution. But note that my `weak_ptr` suggestion **does not** keep the owned object alive too long!

Comment: Also, Rust *does not* have "shared semantics" in the language itself, at least not in the reference-counting sense of `shared_ptr`. It does have reference-counting pointers (a thread-local one and a multithread-appropriate one) in its standard library, though.

Comment: @Galik I've revised each section. The "philosphical" section now has a paragraph clarifying that manual memory management can have concrete benefits. The signal-catching suggestion now includes a paragraph explaining when it *might* be appropriate, and the `shared_ptr` section now includes a mention of your comment about lifetime extension (which was already mentioned in the `weak_ptr` section). I've removed the original parenthetical in the Rust section about C++ fans defending it as a "power language."

Comment: @Galik I've also added a section stating explicitly that the approach already described in the question is the best approach if the system is well designed.